# Data table manipulations in Orange

Tags: orange

I am having some issues doing operations on my data table in Orange.

I need to split my table into two different tables, being a table containing all the instances for y = yes and a table containing all the instances for y = no. How can I most easily do this?

Thank you in advance
Emma

Comment: Welcome to DataScienceSE! I noticed that you posted a few questions recently but unfortunately it seems we don't have any contributor who know Orange these days, sorry.

Comment: Have you tried going over the [tutorial](https://orange-data-mining-library.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and the API reference?